# How do I hide out of stock products from homepage but not from catalog?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, configuration

I know that there is this option on `admin` to hide products from the entire catalog if there is no stock, but how do I hide these products only from home page and not from the entire catalog?

I want to be able to search the products and see it even if it has no stock.

Comment: It depends. How are you displaying the products on the homepage?

Comment: i'm using the `store front` theme with default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using storefront default homepage template. You can filter products before displaying on hompepage

```
function rfl_show_backorders( $is_visible, $id ) {
    $product = new wC_Product( $id );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->backorders_allowed() && is_front_page() ) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }

    return $is_visible;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'rfl_show_backorders', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check current page is **HOME** page like this:

You can check product is *in stock* or not using `$product->is_in_stock()` in your loop.

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
    // Out of products stuff here
}
```

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

To display only **in stock** products you can add `_stock_status` key with the appropriate value to **meta query**.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'wpse_331086_instock_homepage', 20);

function wpse_331086_instock_homepage( $meta_query )
{
    //
    // is_shop()        - apply on shop homepage (product archive page)
    // is_front_page()  - apply on site homepage
    //
    // stock status: 'instock', 'outofstock', 'onbackorder'
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'           => '_stock_status',
            'value'         => 'instock',
            'compare'       => '='
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your theme .

Answer (score 0):

Add this in function.php .. It works for me

```
 <?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
jQuery('.outofstock').parent().parent().css('display','none');
});
</script>
<?php endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_inline_script', 0 );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).